# Local LLM as argument to initialize_agent function in langchain.agents

Tags: langchain, large-language-model, py-langchain

**How to correctly load a local model LLM and use it in the `initialize_agent` function of the langchain library?**

I have a LLM **google/flan-t5-large** (downloaded from HuggingFaces) stored in my computer that would like to load and use as the reasoning engine for a langchain agent as follows:

```
def agent_lookup(name: str) -> str:

    llm = HuggingFacePipeline.from_model_id(model_id = llm_path, task = "text2text-generation")

    lookup_tool = Tool(name = "Get local URL",
                       func = get_local_url,
                       description = "Useful when you need to get local URL")
    tools_for_agent = [lookup_tool]


    agent = initialize_agent(tools_for_agent,
                             llm,
                             agent   = AgentType.ZERO_SHOT_REACT_DESCRIPTION,
                             verbose = True,
                             handle_parsing_errors=True)
```

The agent should call a simple function I wrote called `get_local_url` that simply returns a literal string (just for the sake of testing) provided that the LLM effectively supported the choosing of the custom tool "Get local URL".

Then, we could pass a prompt and run the agent as follows:

```
    # Run the agent providing a fixed prompt_template
    template = "Given the name {name} get me a local URL. Use Get local URL to solve"

    prompt_template = PromptTemplate(template = template,
                                     input_variables = ['name'])

    print(agent.run(prompt_template.format_prompt(name = name)))
```

However, after executing the code above the following output is giving:

[image]

I assume the root of my problem is because I am not taking a correct configuration and combination of LLM and agent. Unfortunately, the documentation of langchain only chooses example with online models (e.g., in particular only in OpenAI models). This is why I initially ask how to correctly load a local model LLM and use it in the `initialize_agent` function of the langchain library.

Thanks in advance.